# Setup router to allow access across subnet masks

Tags: router

I have a /23 network on vlan2 that has a server that can only be on a /24 network.  The server IP is 192.168.1.46/24.  The PC used to access the program is set DHCP with a 0.27/23 ip address.  The Sonicwall is somehow allowing the PC to see the server across different subnet masks.  I'm trying to install a new Checkpoint router and can not figure out how to make it allow the same.  The solution today is to statically set the PC on a 1.xx/23 network to allow it to access the server.  I don't like that solution.  Anyone with a routing or rule suggestion for the Checkpoint?

Comment: What do you see in a packet capture (wireshark) when trying to access that server – does it respond to ARP? (Does the _Sonicwall_ respond to ARP on the server's behalf?)

Answer (score 0):

Network masks do not have to agree for all computers on the local network.
The netmask for a computer only specifies what this computer thinks
is its subnet.
It acts like a filter to only allow devices with certain IP addresses
to communicate with this computer.

This means that the router can use a `/23` netmask and the computer a
`/24` netmask, and as long as the prefix bits are acceptable, both
of them will work happily together.

The router can use this way a `/23` netmask and still serve multiple
more narrow networks that use `/24` netmask. It will also then
allow computers that are on differing `/24` subnets to see computers
on other subnets, if they make the right network requests.

So, although you have a server that only uses a `/24` netmask,
the new router can use a `/23` netmask without problem.